# Android: create and manage a view inside a secondary thread

Tags: java, android

In my app I need to use a specific view (WebView) for use some javascript code in background. This mean the webview have to be offscreen. Initially I created this view inside the UI thread using *runOnUiThread* but I noted when I make some operation into UI (touch the screen for move some object) my background view seem to slow down and is not "resposnive" as required. From here the idea to "execute" this view in a secondary thread for make it independent. I don't know if this will be possible anyway. I started making this code:

```
class WebViewThread extends Thread
{
   public WebView MyWebView = null;

   public void run()
   {
       Looper.prepare();

       MyWebView = new WebView(MainActivityContext);

       Looper.loop();
   }
}
```

The problem is if I try to "interact" with the view calling some method from UI thread I got a runtime error telling me that the view can be touched only by the same thread who create it. Unfortunately this thread is "locked" into loop and I have no idea regarding how to "inject" the interacting code inside this thread.

Now the question: my idea to create and manage a view inside a secondary thread can be done or is a really bad idea that can not work?

Answer (score 0):

As to whether or not that's a good idea, someone more experienced is going to have to elaborate on that subject. For what you're trying to do, though, assuming that you're not touching any UI elements, you could try a handler to pass the code to your webview. See if this works:

```
Handler handler;

class WebViewThread extends Thread
{
    public WebView MyWebView = null;

    public void run() 
    {
       Looper.prepare();
       MyWebView = new WebView(MainActivityContext);

       //the handler will run on the thread
       handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                //do stuff to my webview
            }
        };

       Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

and then you can make the handler do stuff with

```
handler.sendMessage(message);
```

Comment: Hi, it could be a solution but how to get data back?

Comment: Create a method `processData(String data)` or whatever in your encompassing class and call that method from inside your thread when you're done. Remember to wrap it in a `runOnUiThread` if you want it to move to the main thread.

Comment: Just tested but unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to work. Exception error message is the same "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views". :-(